# DTE & DCE advice

Tags: cisco, serial

I am just wondering what the meain differences are between these two and do they need to have different clock rates.

I am right in thinking that if I was linking two routers together via serial I would use DTE to connect them and linking up to an ISP would use the DCE?

thanks

I thought you could just set up two routers via serial and configure them in terminal ans set the clock rate on each side to say 9600

Answer (score 1):

One of the routers should be configured as DCE and other one should be configured as DTE. The DCE provides clock signal to the DTE. This is important to keep them in sync.

Comment: how would i do this? say I have router 1 connected to the ISP and router 1 has 2 small networks and then router 2 is connected to router 1 and has 1 network, how would I condifgue dte and dce on this?

Comment: @mitchnufc: Any cisco manual/tutorial should tell how to do it.